# How to export a scene from Blender, in which I use modifiers and constraints, to Maya and Nuke?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, constraints

I created in Blender ocean and floating object.

How to export this scene to Maya (I need to export this scene to Nuke through Maya)?

Animation of floating object - is not the key animation, made by hand (from key to key, from phase to phase). In order to move "on the waves" floating object analyzes the surface of the ocean.

This is a simple method - I use an invisible object to draw in "dynamic Paint" mode, the area of ​​the ocean where the object should float. And then I make object "copy rotation " and "copy location" (constraints) of this area.
(here is tutorial i used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11F1NRpqrzY)

But I think in Maya and Nuke there is no ocean  modifier and constraints. 
How to export this scene?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! :) You can use the "Bake action"!

If you have an ocean, and an object that "floats" on the surface of the ocean using the method, described in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11F1NRpqrzY)

[image]

do the following:

1) Select a floating object

2) Press T and in the left pane, select the tab "Animation"

3) Press Bake Action, select the frame range and check "clear constraints"

[image]
[image]

4) Voila! You will see a lot of yellow strips in the timeline - the key frames of animation.

[image]

Now, if you delete the ocean and sphere by which you drew in the dynamic Paint mode, floating object will continue to move as before.

[image]